# Legendre polynomial recurrence relation proof using the generation function

Tags: derivatives, summation, recurrence-relations, legendre-polynomials

I want to prove the following recurrence relation for Legendre polynomials:

$$P'_{n+1}(x) − P'_{n−1}(x) = (2n + 1)P_n(x)$$

Using the generating function for the Legendre polynomials which is,

$$(1-2xt+t^2)^{-1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^n P_n(x)$$

I saw there was an "n" saw I figured you would have to get that of the $t^n$ so i differentiated wrt t and doing some rearranging I got

$$(x-t)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t^nP_n(x)=(1-2xt+t^2)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nt^{n-1}P_{n}(x)$$

I pulled out all the coefficents of $t^n$ did some rearranging and got the following

$$(n+1)P_{n+1}(x)= x(2n+1)P_{n}(x) -nP_{n-1}(x)$$

I differentiated that wrt x which gets this

$$ (n+1)P'_{n+1}(x)  = (2n+1)\big[xP'_n(x)+P_{n}(x)\big] -nP_{n-1}(x)$$

And im completely stumped, am i on the right track? If so whats the next step?
And if im completely wrong what should i have done and what clues should i have seen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that your generating function is a function of two variables, so when you are taking partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $t$ and they have different effects.

In fact, you can see that if $f(x,t)=(1-2xt+t^2)^{-1/2}$ then
$$
f_x(x,t)=\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t^nP_n'(x)
$$
whereas
$$
f_t(x,t)=\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nt^{n-1}P_n(x).
$$
Thus, the recurrence relation is equivalent to the following derivative relationship:
$$
\frac{f_x(x,t)-f_x(x,0)}{t}-tf_x(x,t)=2tf_t(x,t)+f(x,t)\qquad (\star)
$$
since if you substitute in the power series, the $t^n$ coefficient on the left side equals $P'_{n+1}(x)-P'_{n-1}(x)$ and on the right side, the $t^n$ coefficient equals $(2n+1)P_n(x)$.

The equation $(\star)$ is a partial differential equation for $f(x,t)$, so all you need to do is compute the two derivatives $f_x(x,t)$ and $f_t(x,t)$, and verify that both sides of $(\star)$ match.